# IR receiver giving constant current

Tags: transistors, infrared, receiver

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzYgYA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This is a circuit I made with an [1838D IR receiver](http://www.datasheetcafe.com/chq1838-datasheet-infrared-receiver/) in order to test if a tv remote is working, but as soon as I press the button, the led faintly lights up, and when I use a remote at the receiver, it just starts blinking. I tried using the transistor you see in the picture in order to make the LED supposedly light up stronger, but because of that constant flow of current out of the receiver, the transistor’s base turns the emitter on, and the LED still faintly lights up, as if there was no transistor.

Is there a way to fix that constant flow of current from the receiver, or is that something receivers are supposed to do?

Comment: Diagram 3 of the datasheet shows you need a pullup resistor from the output pin to Vcc of 20k or more. Diagram 6 shows that the output is HIGH when no IR is sensed and LOW when there is IR. This should be enough information to be able to adjust your circuit to work properly.

Comment: Sorry about the dumb questions, but wich datasheet did you see and what is a pullup resistor?

Comment: and something else: i think i might be exaggerating, but I have a 91K resistor. Will that do it?

Comment: The datasheet is on the website you included in your question! Scroll down to where it says "CHQ1838 Datasheet". Use Google to search for the definition of a Pullup Resistor. And as to 91K: is it more than 20K? Yes. Will it do? Don't know until you try it.

Comment: To test if a TV remote is working you can use a phone camera, though better a cheap one - iPhones may have enough IR filtering to not see it.  Some sort of cheap webcam or security camera would work too.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has been abandoned by the asker

Answer (score 1):

I can’t read the language of the datasheet but, from the schematic it contains, this chip detects a 38kHz IR carrier, and grounds its output when it detects one. Hence, the output is “normally high” (albeit somewhat-high-impedance), hence the “constant flow of current” you experience.

The schematic below should work for you:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIs7OP.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Is that supposed to be the complete circuit?

Comment: Not exactly, you still need your battery, and your 7805 voltage generator.

Comment: The output of the IR receiver IC is missing the 20k pullup resistor needed to turn on Q1 when there is no IR signal.

Answer (score 0):

Logic output from the **OUT** pin idles at the supply voltage (+5V), and goes down to zero volts when the IR-receiver sees a burst of 38 kHz light. When it goes down, the transistor inside may provide enough current to light a LED directly. R1 might be made smaller, perhaps down to 100 ohms:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIAFIR.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The LED should only light when a TV-remote signal is received. Many TV-remotes keep sending repeated codes while a button is pressed: the LED will blink repeatedly.

Comment: I don’t think it is sane to load the output that much. The datasheet says the pull-up resistor should be \$ > 20 \rm k \Omega\$.

Comment: @user2233709 It may be OK if the LED is the only load. Should "OUT" be required to drive a logic device as well as the LED, your caution is well-advised. I have tried this circuit (with a different IR-receiver), and LED illumination was satisfactory.